# Rails Active Record Query - find random record that meets a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, random

I have a model from which I want to pull a random record that meets a certain criteria. For example: give me a random record from table Thing where column_name = true.

To get a random record from the model I can do the following:

```
Thing.offset(rand(Thing.count)).first
```

and I want to combine that with the query:

```
Thing.where("column_name = ?", true).all
```

This doesn't work:

```
counter = Thing.where("column_name = ?", true).count
Thing.where("column_name = ?", true).offset(rand(counter)).first
```

Any ideas on how to write this query would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual query you are trying to achieve.  You actually have a table called "things" with a boolean column entitled" 'column_name'.  I understand you may have changed these value names when posting but since you didn't provide the stack trace or any pertinent information, it's very difficult to provide you assistance

Comment: Just tried your code and adapted to my app, it's working fine ... what's the error?

Comment: You're right. I tried it again and it is working. Not sure what I had wrong last time.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
  counter = Thing.where("column_name = ?", true).count
  Thing.where("column_name = ?", true).limit("#{rand(counter)}, 1").first
```

returning one row that is read from somewhere out of the table.